# Errors deploying bundle to ServiceMix

Tags: maven, jax-rs, bundle, apache-servicemix

I have a JAX RS service I'm trying to deploy to ServiceMix 4.5.2, and it fails with two errors.  I've been following and comparing against various examples, and started with a maven archetype, but I can't find the error or an answer.

First error;

```
2013-09-20 22:45:09,357 | ERROR | lixDispatchQueue | FeatureDeploymentListener        | 35 - org.apache.karaf.deployer.features - 2.2.11 | Unable to install deployed features for bundle: FleetInfoService - 1.0.0.SNAPSHOT
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Malformed \uxxxx encoding.
    at java.util.Properties.loadConvert(Properties.java:569)[:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:391)[:1.6.0_27]
    at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:342)[:1.6.0_27]
    at org.apache.karaf.deployer.features.FeatureDeploymentListener.bundleChanged(FeatureDeploymentListener.java:171)[35:org.apache.karaf.deployer.features:2.2.11]
```

My POM has the following lines wrt/ encoding - provided by the archetype;

```
<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
</properties>
```

In spite of this error, it tries loading bean definitions, and gets this error;

```
2013-09-20 22:45:10,551 | ERROR | ExtenderThread-3 | ContextLoaderListener            | 82 - org.springframework.osgi.extender - 1.2.1 | Application context refresh failed (OsgiBundleXmlApplicationContext(bundle=FleetInfoService, config=osgibundle:/META-INF/spring/*.xml))
org.springframework.beans.factory.parsing.BeanDefinitionParsingException: Configuration problem: Unable to locate Spring NamespaceHandler for XML schema namespace [http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0]
Offending resource: URL [bundle://200.0:0/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml]
```

The camel-context.xml begins with the following, and I've double checked for typos;

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs"
xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxrs.xsd
http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd">
```

The maven POM contains the following dependencies. The camel/blueprint versions match those I see in ServiceMix's osgi:list;

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-blueprint</artifactId>
        <version>2.10.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
        <artifactId>cxf-rt-frontend-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.6</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

POM plugins are;

```
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <configuration>
                <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.tooling</groupId>
            <artifactId>features-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>generate</id>
                    <phase>generate-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>generate-features-xml</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <!-- bundles>src/main/resources/bundles.properties</bundles -->
                        <outputFile>target/${project.artifactId}Features-${project.version}.xml</outputFile>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
            <configuration>
                <instructions>
                    <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                    <Private-Package>${project.groupId}.*</Private-Package>
                    <Import-Package>*</Import-Package>
                </instructions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at FeatureDeploymentListener.cfg file in $SMX/data/cache/bundle/data. It looks like one of the entries there has incorrect content. Look for `\u` sequence or other weird sequences of characters.

Incorrect file can be result of your pom.xml (e.g. your artifactId contains `\u`) or it just might be corrupted. In latter case you can easily remove $SMX/data/cache/bundle directory and restart ServiceMix.

Second problem seems to be caused by the fact that you put OSGI blueprint configuration to spring file (`META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml`). If you want to use blueprint then put your file in `OSGI-INF/blueprint` directory instead. Alternatively you can use Spring DM configuration like [example from camel](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/branches/camel-2.10.x/examples/camel-example-cxf-osgi/src/main/resources/META-INF/spring/camel-context.xml).